# Tradingview : Pinescript - creating a UNION of 2 Series and isolating the last element of a Series

Tags: pine-script

Looking for an answer to two questions.

**Background**: The code I have labels Maximum (and Minimum) Pivot Points.

What I am looking to do is to "pre-identify" a pivot point. The regular Pivot Points are identified with Source = RSI, Limit = 21. Was looking at specifying Source = RSI, Limit = 5 to "pre-identify" a possible Pivot Point (drawn with GRAY labels).

If there is a better way to do this, I am all ears/eyes

**QUESTION 1**

In the case I am working on, I did the following

1. plotted the RED labels   (used Series : result is OB_pivot_data -
   see code - with Source = RSI, length = 21 )
2. plotted the GREEN labels (used Series : result is OS_pivot_data -
   see code - with Source = RSI, length = 21 )
3. plotted the GRAY labels  (used Series with Source = RSI, length = 5
   )

For the GRAY labels, I just want the ~last~ value (in this case, it is 67.06). I `need to have the last value in series` form (in this case upper_bound_pivot[0] = 67.06)  **See picture below**  In the picture *BEFORE* is what I have now. *AFTER* is what the target is.

**QUESTION 2**

Next, I want to combine the resulting series with another (acting like a UNION). With that being said, is there a way to implement something like `Series A UNION Series B`?

It is listed in the code below using:

```
// HOWTO : OB_pivot_data UNION testme
```

How can one accomplish these two tasks under Pinescript?

Any help, hint or advice would be greatly appreciated.

TIA

**Picture**
[image]

**FUNCTION PIVOTHL:**

```
pivothl(src, len, isHigh, _style, _yloc, _color, _offset, _displayResults ) =>
    p = nz(src[len])
    isFound = true
    for i = 0 to len - 1
        if isHigh and src[i] > p
            isFound := false

        if not isHigh and src[i] < p
            isFound := false

    for i = len + 1 to 2 * len
        if isHigh and src[i] >= p
            isFound := false

        if not isHigh and src[i] <= p
            isFound := false

    if _displayResults and isFound
        label.new(bar_index[len], p , tostring( truncate(p, 2) ), style=_style, yloc=_yloc, color=_color, textcolor=color.white)
        
    return_data = isFound == false ? na : p
```

**FUNCTION PIVOTHL_FIRST_ONLY**

```
pivothl_first_only(src, len, isHigh, _style, _yloc, _color, _offset, _displayResults ) =>

    start_src = src    
    
    upper_bound_pivot = pivothl(start_src, len, true, _style, _yloc, _color, _offset, true )
    
    return_data = upper_bound_pivot == false ? na : upper_bound_pivot
    
    return_data
```

**MAIN**

```
pivot_OB_LB = input(title="Pivot Over Bought Lookback :", type=input.integer, defval=21 )
pivot_OS_LB = input(title="Pivot Over Sold Lookback :", type=input.integer, defval=21 )
pivot_OB_LB_peek = input(title="Peek Pivot Over Bought Lookback :", type=input.integer, defval=5)

lenH = pivot_OB_LB
lenL = pivot_OS_LB

OB_pivot_data = pivothl(rsi, lenH, true , label.style_labeldown, yloc.price, color.red,0, true)
OS_pivot_data = pivothl(rsi, lenL, false, label.style_labelup  , yloc.price, color.green,0, true )

dbug_OB_pivot_data = OB_pivot_data >= 0 ? OB_pivot_data : 0
dbug_OS_pivot_data = OS_pivot_data >= 0 ? OS_pivot_data : 100 // just arbitrary number chosen (100)

[ ... snip ... ]

// get last value only place into series 
testme = pivothl_first_only(rsi, pivot_OB_LB_peek, true , label.style_labeldown, yloc.price, color.silver,0, false)
pl_testme = testme > 0 ? testme : 0
plot( pl_testme, offset = -pivot_OB_LB_peek, color=color.purple )
```

Comment: If you provide a working scenario for the study, I will try to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: this is what I found worked for me (seems to be working ...):

pivothl_combine_upper_and_lower (src, len, oBought, oSold ) =>

```
combined = 0.0
if print_OBought != 0
    p = src[len]
    combined := p
else 
    if print_OSold != 0
        p = src[len]
        combined := p

combined
```